# Own CSS Grid: Table heading width is not related to table data width

Tags: html, css, grid

Since I do not use Bootstrap, I created my own CSS grid and tried to apply this to a simple table. But when I set width to the `<th>` using my grid classes, this width does not apply to the `<td>`. My first table data takes all the width of the table pushing other four table data outside of the table. Does anybody know why?

Here is the code snippet of my table and CSS grid:

```css
   .container-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    /* GRID STYLE */

    .container-grid {
      width: 100%;
      box-shadow: -3px 0 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
      padding: 0 36px 0 36px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .row:before,
    .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table ;
      clear: both;
    }

    [class*='col-'] {
      float: left;
      min-height: 1px;
      width: 8.33%;
      text-align: left;
      /* gutter */
      padding: 12px;
    }
    .col-1{
      width: 8.33%;
    }
    .col-2{
      width: 16.66%;
    }
    .col-3{
      width: 25%;
    }
    .col-4{
      width: 33.33%;
    }
    .col-5{
      width: 41.66%;
    }
    .col-6{
      width: 50%;
    }
    .col-7{
      width: 58.33%;
    }
    .col-8{
      width: 66.66%;
    }
    .col-9{
      width: 75%;
    }
    .col-10{
      width: 83.33%;
    }
    .col-11{
      width: 91.66%;
    }
    .col-12{
      width: 100%;
```

```html
    <div>
        <table class="table col-12">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="col-2 add">Added</th>
            <th class="col-5 file">File</th>
            <th class="col-1 size">Size</th>
            <th class="col-2 status">Status</th>
            <th class="col-2 completed">Completed</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-2 add">16:54 16/01/2018</td>
            <td class="col-5 file">sdf_fsdfsdf_fdsfsdfsdf.xlsx</td>
            <td class="col-1 size">1,32 Мб</td>
            <td class="col-2 status">
              <button>Processing</button>
            </td>
            <td class="col-2 completed">16/01/2018 15:23</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-2 add">16:54 16/01/2018</td>
            <td class="col-5 file">my_uber_file.csv</td>
            <td class="col-1 size">1,32 Мб</td>
            <td class="col-2 status">
              <button>Processing</button>
            </td>
            <td class="col-2 completed">16/01/2018 15:23</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can u please give us more information, I need the css classes you made to reproduce your problem, also, if possible, consider to make a snippet.

Comment: Done, please have a look. :)

Comment: can u tell me how to reproduce the problem? And what exactly do u expect to happen?

Comment: So, for now, our table looks okay. However, as you can see, the width of `<td>` is actually set by additional classes. If you remove these classes, all the `<td>` will not be set their width automatically (width of `<th>`) and the first one will take the whole space pushing other `<td>` away.

Comment: I just removed, all the css from the fiddle, and the <th> elements took the normal width, that is, the width of the <td> elements bellow them, which was exactly enough to show the <td>'s content. There is no movement of the <td>'s to take all the space...and they are lined up as they should, change in the 5th line the width parameter, and you will see that all <td> elements mach up with their <th> elements, check it out here: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3ffz0p5/10/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I checked your solution and repeated this in my project. Before this, I deleted all my style related to the table. And it worked out. Probably, I had another mistake or property which didn't allow me to place my table in the way I want.

Comment: np, glad I could help :)